# Phpdocs on local array

Tags: php, phpdoc

My code review was refused by my co-worker, because of an unnecessary phpdoc on a local array (`$params` in bottom example) in a function. See the example:

```
/**
 * comment...
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function testFunction()
{
    /** @var string[] $params */
    $params = ['string1', 'string2'];

    etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why defining phpdocs on local arrays is unnecessary? I got an explanation from my co-worker that we don't need to write phpdocs on local arrays. We are using PhpStorm and Doctrine.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: This is entirely opinion-based.  Many people prefer PHPDoc on all local variables.  In this case, I would personally be using PHPDoc, as you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a phpdoc like `string[]` for an array is useful when the array is a parameter or a return value, so you can specify what types of values the array should contain. But in that case it's an array of string literals defined right there. The phpdoc isn't telling you anything you can't know just by looking at it.

Technically [`@var`](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) is intended to document class properties, but in some cases it can be useful inside a function to help the IDE when it's unable to determine the type of a variable. That's not really needed here either, though.

I can't know for sure if that's exactly why your co-worker thought it was unnecessary, but I don't see another logical explanation for it.